# How can I be a plugin developer?

Tags: plugins

To be a wordpress plugin developer, what things should I know. I know basic php.
I want to make a custom plugin development/customize plugin  for client. 
For this, how can I start to learn ? anybody can suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

I've also the started learning plugin development. and i found this [playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLIjMj0-5C8TI7Jwell1rTvv5XXyrbKDcy) so much helpful.
Here he shows how to develop e plugin very easily. complete this series, i think you'll know where to go next!
Best of luck!